# Remove defined character from a string using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
a = "!@$%^"
s = "sfe@v%asfr"
for i in a:
  w = s.replace(i,' ')
print(w)
```

My output      : `sfe@v%asfr`

Desired output : `sfe v asfr`

How to get the desired output?

Comment: Since they're all single characters, this is really easy to do with a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html): `w = re.sub(f"[{a}]", " ", s)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign `s` the replaced string. `w` is just being over written with every iteration.

```
a = "!@$%^"
s = "sfe@v%asfr"
for i in a:
  s = s.replace(i,' ')
print(s)
```